# GMM estimation of the CAPM allowing for time-varying expectation of market's excess return

Tags: capm, estimation, gmm

With **time-constant** expected value of market's excess return, we can estimate the CAPM using GMM as follows. Equation $(12.23)$ in Cochrane ["Asset Pricing"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691121376/asset-pricing) (2005) section 12.2 (p. 241) says the moments are
$$
g_T(b) = \begin{bmatrix} E(R^e_t-a-\beta f_t) \\ E[(R^e_t-a-\beta f_t)f_t] \\ E(R^e-\beta \lambda) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{12.23}.
$$
where $R^e_t=(R^e_{1,t},\dots,R^e_{N,t})'$ is a vector of individual assets' excess returns, $\beta=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_N)'$ is a vector of betas, $f_t$ is factor's excess return and $\lambda=E(f)$ is the expected value of the factor's excess return. The first two rows correspond to time series regressions for $N$ assets (one regression per asset), so there are actually $2N$ conditions. If I understand correctly, the third row corresponds to a cross-sectional regression of time-averaged returns:
$$
E_T(R^{ei})=\beta_i' \lambda+\alpha_i, \quad i=1,2,\dots,N. \tag{12.10}
$$
($(12.10)$ is specified for potentially many factors, but $(12.23)$ considers the simple case of a single factor, so vector $\beta'$ turns into scalar $\beta$, and the same holds for $\lambda$.)

**Question:** Could this be modified to allow for **time-varying** expectation of market's excess return ($\lambda_t$ in place of $\lambda$)? If so, how should the moment conditions be modified?